# Can I use any HV Probe for a Voltmeter/Ampmeter gauge?

Tags: power-supply, high-voltage, multimeter, probe

I purchased the multimeter pictured below for a high voltage power supply I'm working on. It's rated for 100V DC and 10A, but I hope to measure several thousand volts. Is it possible to use a HV voltage probe like I would use with a regular multimeter on this component, or no?
[image: Voltmeter/Ampmeter gauge]

Answer (score 4):

No. Those cheap meters use a voltage divider adding up to around 280-290K and go directly into an 8-bit MCU (STM8 series).

Typical high voltage probes assume a reasonably accurate 10M\$\Omega\$ input impedance for the multimeter- something like 999M in series with 1.11M (internal divider values), so it would read grossly low on this kind of an input.

Comment: It would be highly impractical to manually account for a very uneven correction factor, but OP would be able to feed it higher voltages than before :-)

Comment: @winny but only once, I guess.

Comment: How come? The probe division should take the majority of the voltage.

Comment: @winny If it's rated for 40kV but only outputs roughly 1/3 the voltage, connecting it to a 120kV source might not be wise. ;-)

Comment: Of course! Hence correction factor!

Comment: Correction applied posthumously.

Answer (score 0):

Only if the input impedances are the same to form a voltage divider.